# Pitch interpolation using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, audio, linear-interpolation

I have a numpy array containing 88200 elements representing a 2 second audio sample sampled with sample rate 44.1 kHz. The pitch of the sample is assumed to be 130.8 Hz. I can interpolate the audio data and stretch it into a 4 second sample which would halve the pitch or squeeze it into a 1 second sample which would double the pitch.

I want to implement pitch sliding (portamento). That is, some kind of interpolation so that the pitch starts at 130.8 Hz and smoothly slides up to 261.6 Hz when the sample ends.

How can I do this using Python and numpy? I think I should be able to pull this off using the `linspace` and `interp` functions, but I can't get it to work correctly.

Comment: To glide the pitch, the interpolation will be at changing points in the array. You'd probably be best writing your own function so you can  easily swap in linear, spline and Lagrange interpolation. If you have an audio `buffer` that you are slowing down and you ask for indices `0`, `0.5`, `1`, `1.4`, there isn't a straight linear interp for the `0.5` and `1.4` indices, you would need to take it case by case.

Comment: Is it OK for you to use non-numpy libraries? Not like it's not possible to stick to numpy, but doing this well is non-trivial.

Comment: I actually solved my problem using numpy! I'll write an answer shortly. If you or anyone else can improve on it I'd like to see it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the numpy code I ended up using:

```
def slide_sample(arr, v1):
    x_old = np.linspace(0, arr.size, arr.size)
    v0 = 1
    ratio = 2 / (v0 + v1)
    vels = np.linspace(v0, v1, int(arr.size * ratio))
    x_new = np.append([0], np.cumsum(vels))
    return np.interp(x_new, x_old, arr)
```

`arr` is the sample array to slide and `v1` is the relative pitch to slide to. So `slide_sample(arr, 2)` would slide to twice the pich and `slide_sample(arr, 0.5)` to half the pitch.